# Localstack. Permission denied initial script

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, docker-compose, localstack

I have the first project with docker compose file:

```
version: '3'

services:
  ...other services...

  localstack:
    container_name: localstack
    image: localstack/localstack:2.3
    hostname: localstack
    env_file:
      - /.env
    ports:
      - "4566:4566"
      - 8080:8080
    environment:
      - SERVICES=s3,ses
      - DEBUG=${DEBUG- }
      - DOCKER_HOST=unix:///var/run/docker.sock
      - HOSTNAME=localstack
    networks:
      - ntwk1
    volumes:
      - localstack-data:/tmp/localstack
      - "/var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock"
      - ./localstack-script.sh:/etc/localstack/init/ready.d/script.sh

volumes:
  localstack-data:
networks:
  ntwk1:
    external: true
```

Here localstack-script.sh works correctly and everything is okay. But if I do it in other docker-compose file it fails.
My localstack-srcipt.sh:

```
#!/bin/bash

awslocal s3api \
create-bucket --bucket $S3_BUCKET_NAME \
--create-bucket-configuration LocationConstraint=eu-central-1 \
--region eu-central-1
```

Then I created another project with another docker-compose file:

```
version: '3'

services:
  ... other services...

  localstack_1:
    container_name: localstack_1
    image: localstack/localstack:2.3
    hostname: localstack_1
    env_file:
      - .env
    ports:
      - "4567:4566"
      - 8081:8080
    environment:
      - SERVICES=s3
      - DEBUG=${DEBUG- }
      - DOCKER_HOST=unix:///var/run/docker.sock
      - HOSTNAME=localstack_1
    networks:
      - ntwk
    volumes:
      - localstack1:/tmp/localstack
      - "/var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock"
      - ./localstack-script.sh:/etc/localstack/init/ready.d/script.sh
volumes:
  localstack1:
networks:
  ntwk:
    external: true
```

And it gives error:

```
ERROR --- [  MainThread] localstack.runtime.init    : Error while running script Script(path='/etc/localstack/init/ready.d/script.sh', stage=READY, state=ERROR): [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/etc/localstack/init/ready.d/script.sh'
```

In the dockerfile I give permissions to .sh files using `RUN chmod +x`

Comment: Since you're mounting the script into the container with `volumes:`, anything you do in a Dockerfile won't affect it.  (Are you using a custom Dockerfile at all, or just running the unmodified `localstack/localstack:2.3` image?)  Is the script executable on the host?

Comment: @DavidMaze I have another service in docker-compose and the service depends on the localstack service. Dockerfile for that service gives permissions to all .sh scripts I want

Comment: How does that work?  A Dockerfile can't affect files on the host.

Comment: Could you tell me where you run the command `RUN chmod +x`? In my opinion, your script just doesn't have the proper execution permissions that's why it cannot be executed when mounted. You would just have to update the permissions at the right place.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are mounting your script as volume, the script has to be executable. Check permissions on your script `localstack-script.sh` and if the script is not executable give it the permission. [`chmod +x`]